# Фильтр плохих слов определяет только английские слова, но не русские, как поправить?

Tags: php

Через поиск нашёл вот такой [интересный код контактной формы с проверкой на плохие слова](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185920/spam-filter-in-contact-form). Т.е. при попытке отправить сообщение, в котором имеется плохое слово или слова, выводится сообщение.

Вот часть того кода, где происходит проверка.

```
$MessageArray = explode(" ", $message);
//Get SPAM words from file and store them in an array
$SpamWords = file_get_contents('spamwords.txt');
$SpamArray = explode("\r\n", $SpamWords);
//Cycle through all the words in the message
foreach($MessageArray as $word){
//Check the word for SPAM words, if it is don't send the email
if(in_array($word, $SpamArray)){
echo '<h1>Spam Guard...';
die();
}
}
```

Но проблема в том, что воспринимаются корректно только английские слова, а написанные на русском не определяются. Как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что код английский и писался в первую очередь под тот язык. В файлах попросту нет русских слов. Однако, не исключено, что где-то есть ошибка. Это один из возможных вариантов.

Comment: Что значит не определяются? $SpamArray пустой получается?

Answer (score 0):

Файл `spamwords.txt` должен содержать в том числе и русские слова. Необходимо убедиться, что кодировка `spamwords.txt` и текста в запросе совпадают (вероятно ваша проблема именно тут). И ещё переносы строк в `spamwords.txt` должны быть именно `\r\n` (что не всегда так).

Проверьте кодировку. Посмотрите что происходит в коде: сократите список спам-слов до одного "тест", введите в форму "тест" и сделайте `var_dump($MessageArray, $SpamArray)`.